# Ember-cordova sample app : index.html not found

Tags: cordova, ember.js, hybrid-mobile-app

I built a simple ember-cordova app. When i ran ember cordova emulate which it gives an apk file but when the app opens up in the emulator it says

```
"net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)".
```

I have removed all references to {{rootURL}} from index.html and also remove the leading slash from rootURL. locationType is also set to hash.

Comment: can you share your code then we can answers you better thanks

Comment: @HassanALi There is no code.. i just did an "ember new myapp" and then i installed ember-cordova add on. I have not made any changes to the ember code other than what was required by ember-cordova. I have removed all references to {{rootURL}} from index.html and also remove the leading slash from rootURL. locationType is also set to hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My build was failing, that's why i was getting the file not found error. However the build was failing with a "Undefined error". I had to remove the platform using

```
ember cordova platform remove android
```

and reinstall it using

```
ember cordova platform add android
```

After doing these steps, it started working.